# Print the digit from the first to the last as a text with out using arrays, recursion or binary operation in C

Tags: c, back, digit

I need to print the digit from the first to the last without use arrays, binary operations or recursion. In addition every digit should be print as a text.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  int a,x;

  printf("Give a number : ");
  scanf("%i", &a);
  do {
    switch ( x % 10 ) {
      case 0 :
        printf("zero ");
        break;
      case 1 :
        printf("one ");
        break;
      case 2 :
        printf("two ");
        break;
      case 3 :
        printf("three ");
        break;
      case 4 :
        printf("four ");
        break;
      case 5 :
        printf("five ");
        break;
      case 6 :
        printf("six ");
        break;
      case 7 :
        printf("seven ");
        break;
      case 8 :
        printf("eight ");
        break;
      case 9 :
        printf("nine ");
        break;
      default:
        printf("Error \n");
        break;
    }
    x /= 10;
  } while ( a );
  printf("\n");
}
```

The output for 123 is three two one. The desirable: one two three.
Any ideas?

Comment: Reverse the prints. case 9 :
        printf("zero ");

Comment: @Oscar - really?  So if their input is 999 it should print zero zero zero?

Comment: To the OP - your program is will print gibberish as you never assign a to x.  Also, it's not clear what you want and what you get.

Comment: *Why* did you tag this as `recursion`, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the number before passing it to the Switch statement. See if the following program works. i haven't tested it yet.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  int a, temp, reverse = 0;



  printf("Give a number : ");
  scanf("%i", &a);
       temp = a;

 while (temp != 0)
 {
     reverse = reverse * 10;
     reverse = reverse + temp%10;
     temp    = temp/10;
 }

  do {
    switch ( reverse % 10 ) {
      case 0 :
        printf("zero ");
        break;
      case 1 :
        printf("one ");
        break;
      case 2 :
        printf("two ");
        break;
      case 3 :
        printf("three ");
        break;
      case 4 :
        printf("four ");
        break;
      case 5 :
        printf("five ");
        break;
      case 6 :
        printf("six ");
        break;
      case 7 :
        printf("seven ");
        break;
      case 8 :
        printf("eight ");
        break;
      case 9 :
        printf("nine ");
        break;
      default:
        printf("Error \n");
        break;
    }
    reverse /= 10;
  } while ( reverse );
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: why go through the unnecessary step of reversing?

Comment: I think his main concern is the fact that a number like 256 prints as "six five two" and not "two five six". That's why the number needs to be reversed first so that the rest of his program works as desired.

Comment: I based my solution on his title as it's not clear if he wants the numbers forwards or backwards.  If the former, then reversing the digits is necessary.

Comment: @KevinDTimm Read the last line of the question.

Comment: @user3386109 - which directly contradicts the title and first sentence :(

Comment: @KevinDTimm Perhaps, but English isn't everybody's first language, so sample input and output takes precedence over loose interpretations of the title. In any case, there's nothing difficult about the problem if you can print the number backwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the digits in number and then use the / instead %.

For example, for 123 there are 3 digits, so you calculate pow (10,3-1) that is equal to 100. Then, 123/100 is equal to one. After that new number get 123%100 and next time you divide by 100/10. So 23/10 is equal to 2. Until you reach the less than 10 number and print that at the end. So 3 printed finally.